# How to replace all events in FullCalendar library

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am creating a page using the FullCalendar.io library to display events on a webpage.

Now as the user navigates between between date ranges I want to load the events dynamically. Using the documentation I'm able to add the new events when the user presses the "next" button, however it simply appends the events to the existing events Object, what I want to do is remove any existing events and only display the new list. How can I do this?

You can view the functionality [here on my CodePen](https://codepen.io/sfdxnotfound/pen/vMvdRW).

**HTML**

```
  <p>
    <button id='prev'>prev</button>
    <button id='next'>next</button>
  </p>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**JS**

```
var calendar;
var eventsList = [{
  id: '1',
  title: 'event 1',
  start: '2019-04-06'
},
                  {
                    id: '2',
                    title: 'event 2',
                    start: '2019-04-07'
                  },
                  {
                    id: '3',
                    title: 'event 3',
                    start: '2019-04-29'
                  },
                  {
                    id: '4',
                    title: 'event 4',
                    start: '2019-04-30'
                  }];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid' ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
    header: {
      left: '',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    editable: true,
    events: eventsList

  });

  calendar.render(); 

});

document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
  calendar.prev(); // call method
});

document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', function() {

  // replace existing list - this will doneby another function, hard coding for demo
  eventsList = [{
    id: '5',
    title: 'event 5',
    start: '2019-05-06'
  },
                {
                  id: '6',
                  title: 'event 6',
                  start: '2019-05-07'
                },
                {
                  id: '7',
                  title: 'event 7',
                  start: '2019-05-08'
                },
                {
                  id: '8',
                  title: 'event 7',
                  start: '2019-05-09'
                }];
  calendar.next(); // call method
  calendar.addEventSource(eventsList);
  //calendar.refetchEvents(); // using this instead of the line above does not work either, just loads original list
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misread the document, `getEventSource` returns an array of eventSource, so just simply point index and then remove should work.

```js
  calendar.getEventSources()[0].remove();
```

or if you have multiple resources,

```js
  calendar.getEventSources().forEach(eventSource => {
    eventSource.remove()
  })
```

---

**Code below is mistaken, left for the record.**

How about adding `remove()` before you add event source.

```js
  calendar.next(); // call method
  calendar.getEventSources().remove();
  calendar.addEventSource(eventsList);
  //calendar.refetchEvents(); // this does not work either, just loads original list
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventSources
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/EventSource-remove

Comment: I think the `remove()` function only works for individual events. I've tried running `remove()` before adding the source list but this breaks, no new events are added (nor are the old events removed).